# IF IF THEN INDEX THIS or INDEX MATCH&MATCH?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Ok, got a formula problem. I need to list all the PO lines for a certain buyer that have a remainder greater than zero.

I need to populate the buyer's dashboard with data from the buyer's dashboard data. Note: Each PO may have one or more lines that need to be listed in order and both sheets are in one workbook.

Buyer’s Dashboard:
[image: Buyer’s Dashboard]

Buyer’s Dashboard Data:
[image: Buyer’s Dashboard Data]

Here are the approaches I have tried:
 `=IFERROR(INDEX(Download!$B$2:$B$50000,MATCH(TRUE,$B$3,Download!$C$2:$C$50000>0,0)),"")`

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Download!$B$2:$B$50000,MATCH($B$3&>0,Download!C2:C50000&DownloadG2:G50000,0)),"")`

`=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($B$3,$C$2:$C$50000)),FALSE,TRUE),ROW($C$2:$C$50000)),ROW($B$2:$B$50000))),"",INDEX($A$2:$K$50000,SMALL(IF(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($B$3,$C$2:$C$50000)),FALSE,TRUE),ROW($$C$2:$C$50000)),ROW($B$2:B50000)),3))`

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Download!A2:K50000,SMALL(IF(Download!C2:C50000=$B$3,ROW(Download!B2:B50000)),ROW(1:1))-1,3)),"",INDEX(Download!A2:K50000,SMALL(IF(Download!C2:C50000=$B$3,ROW(Download!B2:B50000)),ROW(1:1))-1,3))`

Any ideas????

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75337/discussion-on-question-by-jon-h-if-if-then-index-this-or-index-matchmatch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach to making dynamic lists of things in Excel.

Suppose you had an array of the row numbers where your criteria are `TRUE` (i.e. Buyer Code = JDH and Remaining > 0).  Then you could feed that array to a `SMALL()` function that would list the row numbers as it was filled down.  And finally, you could use the `SMALL()` as the `row_nums` in an `INDEX()` function, and that would list the appropriate values of any column you specify with the `column_num` parameter.

So let's start by getting an array of the row numbers.  For simplicity, I'm going to assume your data table has only 25 rows, and that the Dashboard is on the same sheet as the data.  Also, I'm using the Buyer Code ELN, which is in cell B30.

First we'll calculate an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values corresponding to your criteria:

`($C$1:$C$25=$B$30)*($G$1:$G$25>0)`

The first expression gives an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values where Buyer Code (column C) = ELN, and the second gives an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values where Remaining (column G) is > 0.  In arithmetic operations involving logical values, `TRUE` and `FALSE` are converted to 1's and 0's, so this multiplication gives an array of 1's and 0's with 1's in the positions where your criteria are both `TRUE`.

Now we need to convert this array into a list of the row numbers where your criteria are `TRUE`.  If we divide an array of sequential numbers by this array of 1's and 0's, we'll get an array of the row numbers wherever there is a 1, interspersed with `#DIV/0!` errors wherever there is a 0.

`ROW($1:$25)/(($C$1:$C$25=$B$30)*($G$1:$G$25>0))`

Next, instead of `SMALL()`, we'll use `AGGREGATE()`, which does the same thing that `SMALL()` would do (function=15), except it has an option to ignore errors (option=6). Also `AGGREGATE()` can handle arrays without having to enter it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

So in the formula below, `AGGREGATE()` ignores the `#DIV/0!` errors, and gives an array containing just the row numbers that match your criteria:

`AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$25)/(($C$1:$C$25=$B$30)*($G$1:$G$25>0)),ROW()-33)`

I have this formula in row 34, so the "-33" makes the function start at 1 and list the row numbers as it's filled down. Change this parameter to fit your situation.

Now we can use this in an INDEX() and wrap the whole thing in an `IFERROR()` to insert blanks when `INDEX()` runs out of `row_nums` as it's filled down.  This formula, filled down and right from B34:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:G$25,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$25)/(($C$1:$C$25=$B$30)*($G$1:$G$25>0)),ROW()-33),MATCH(B$32,$A$1:$G$1,0)),"")`

gives the results shown below.

[image]

For Buyer ELN, only rows 5 and 11 have 0 Remaining, and the formula lists all rows except those.

Note that I referred to the dashboard headers in the `MATCH()` that gives the `column_num's`by using `B$32` as the `lookup_value`.  When the formula is filled across, this works for PO Number and Description, but the other headings in the Dashboard aren't the same as the headings in your data table.

So for the other columns, I replaced the cell reference `B$32` with quoted text: "LINE_NBR" for the PO Line column, "QUANTITY" for the Qty Ordered column and "REMAINING" for the Qty Received column.  This last column involves a calculation, so the formula is actually:

`=E34-IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:G$25,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$25)/(($C$1:$C$25=$B$30)*($G$1:$G$25>0)),ROW()-33),MATCH("REMAINING",$A$1:$G$1,0)),"")`

The last column, "Needed", is calculated as:

`=E34-F34`, and filled down.

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: This is AWESOME, Thank you! I tried to replace the > with < and the formula failed to work. Any Idea why?

Comment: Do you have any numbers in column G that are less than zero?

Comment: No, all numbers in column G are 0 or a positive number.

Comment: Basically, I want to only show PO lines in which the Qty Received is less than or not equal to the Qty Ordered. =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:G$25,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$25)/(($C$1:$C$25=$B$30)*($G$1:$G$25<>F2:F25)),ROW()-33),MATCH(B$32,$A$1:$G$1,0)),"")

Comment: Let's talk about this in terms of the columns in the Dashboard Data table, since that's where the Dashboard data has to come from.  Since Qty Ordered = QUANTITY and Qty Received = QUANTITY - REMAINING, the PO lines where Qty Received is less than (and not equal) to the Qty Ordered is exactly those rows where REMAINING is > 0.  That's what the formulas give now.

Comment: The formula you've shown is different than the words you've written, but for it to work correctly, replace F2:F25 with $F$1:$F$25.  If you get a #VALUE! error, then enter it with CTRL+Shift+Enter.